# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de un Select - Option, ya sea en Ajax, JavaScript, PHP o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, aplicación-web

necesito saber como obtengo el valor de los select option, he visto varios videos pero todos explican como llenar los select desde la base de datos, mas no como obtener el valor de cada select. esto es lo que yo tengo, al intentar hacerlo, me pudo dar los resultados pero obtenia los numeros osea los ID de cada nombre de cada select que tenia en mi base de datos. este es mi codigo.

mi conexion a la base de datos.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'tutorial';

$db = new mysqli($host,$username,$pass,$db);

if ($db->connect_error) {
 die("Connection Failed". $db->connect_error);
}

?>
```

despues tengo un php donde mando a llamar a mi tabla para llenar cada select que tengo

```
<?php 
include_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['id_marca'])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM modelo where id_delamarca=".$_POST['id_marca'];
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        echo '<option value="">Elige el Modelo</option>';
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['nom_modelo'].'</option>';
     }
}else{
    echo '<option>Estado no encontrado</option>';
}
}elseif (isset($_POST['id_modelo'])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM anio where id_delmodelo=".$_POST['id_modelo'];
$result = $db->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        echo '<option value="">Elige el Año</option>';
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['num_anio'].'</option>';
     }
}else{
    echo '<option>Municipio no encontrado</option>';
}
}
?>
```

este es mi html

```
 <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Marca</label>
      <select name="marca" id="marca" class="form-control" 
    onchange="FetchModelo(this.value)" required>
        <option value="">Seleccionar Marca</option>
      <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
           while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['nom_marca'].'</option>';
           }
        }
      ?> 
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Modelo</label>
      <select name="modelo" id="modelo" class="form-control" 
    onchange="FetchAnio(this.value)" required>
        <option>Selecciona Modelo</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Año</label>
      <select name="anio" id="anio" class="form-control">
        <option>Selecciona el Año</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

y por ultimo en ajax, para obtener y que sean dependientes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function FetchModelo(id){
   $('#modelo').html('');
   $('#anio').html('<option>Elige Año</option>');
   $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url: 'ajaxdata.php',
  data : { id_marca : id},
  success : function(data){
     $('#modelo').html(data);
  }

 })
}

function FetchAnio(id){ 
$('#anio').html('');
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url: 'ajaxdata.php',
  data : { id_modelo : id},
  success : function(data){
     $('#anio').html(data);
  }

 })
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

primero te comento que tu primer select id="marca" tiene dos "onchange" lo cual te puede ocasionar problemas, tambien recibes el id porque configuraste que el value de cada option fuera el valor del campo id de tu tabla, si asi lo requieres entonces podrias mandar solo el this en la función del onchange y dentro de esa función obtener el texto y el id de la opción seleccionada de esta forma:

```
  function FetchModelo(sel){
    let texto=sel.selectedOptions[0].text;
    let id= sel.selectedOptions[0].value;
    ....
    }
```